# Weird compiler error with GCC (codeblocks)

Tags: c, macros

When I try to compile this (I'm trying to understand what ## does here), I get an error saying: "i2 undeclared". I dont' have a variable by that name, this is all the code I have.

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define A(x,y) x##2-y


int main()
{
    int i = -1;
    int j = -2;
    printf("%d \n", A(i,j));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect? Just look up what the `##` _concatenation operator_ does (and why it is called like that).

Comment: Where is the "i2" variable the compiler is complaining about. I didn't use it.

Comment: when you pass i as a parameter in function A(), does preprocessor takes it as i, and concatanates with 2 ?

Comment: I already did, @FiddlingBits

Answer (score 5):

`##` simply means form a new pre-processor constant out of two expresions ("paste together").

Your macro expands to `i##2-j` which is the same as `i2-j`. You have nothing called `i2`, which is the compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

After preprocessing, this statement

```
printf("%d \n", A(i,j));
```

becomes:

```
printf("%d \n", i2-j);
```

As you can see, there's no variable `i2` in your code. Hence, the error. 
`##` is called [*token pasting operator*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html), which *pastes* the two tokens `i` and `2` together and it becomes `i2`.

Answer (score 3):

`##` concatenates its operands. So for `A(i,j)`, you get `i##2-y`, which after concatenation becomes `i2-y`. And since, as you say, you don't define a variable `i2` anywhere in your code, you rightly get an error that `i2` does not exist.